# How to put different graphs on the same subplot in R (with plotly)

Tags: r, plotly, subplot

My problem is the following, I have 3 dataframes in R which have nothing in common and I would like to create a subplot (of 3 pie charts). When I   execute my subplot, I only get the last plot and not a subplot graph. 
Below is my code :

```
x = data.frame(country = c("F", "GB", "DE"), number = c(13, 9, 21))
y = data.frame(type = c("pork", "chicken"), number = c(342, 74))
z = data.frame(pg = c("ca", "na", "br", "al"), number = c(23.4, 1.8, 0.66, 6.1))

p1 = plot_ly(x, labels = ~country, values = ~number, type = 'pie')
p2 = plot_ly(y, labels = ~type, values = ~number, type = 'pie')
p3 = plot_ly(z, labels = ~pg, values = ~number, type = 'pie')

subplot(p1, p2, p3, nrows = 2, margin = 0.05)
```

What I want is 3 pie chart in the same row and 3 columns, 
or,
2 pie charts on one row and the last one on the second row

Comment: Also see https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/655.